# Can't delete printer or add a new one

Tags: printer

My printer doesn't work. It appears in the settings but I can't delete it:
[image: trying to add]

If I try to add it again nothings happens.

Any idea how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Since eos uses CUPS for printing if you check cupsd (browse to http://localhost:631 is one way) you should see the printers that are installed. You can add/change/delete printers from this interface as well. Once I made some changes (deleted multiple installs of home printer) the standard printer window was updated.